# Prettier - Break html classes in multiple lines

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, format, tailwind-css, prettier

I'm trying to achieve a behavior using prettier formatter plugin on vscode that, **when a html tag has several classes it breaks every class in a line for each**, but **only when that class line reach the "Word Wrap Column" limit** (vscode config). Is it possible?

**Current behavior**

```
    <div                                                                                             | - LINE LIMIT
        class="m-10 flex min-h-screen items-center justify-center rounded-2xl border-2 border-red-500
        bg-indigo-500 p-10 shadow-2xl"
    ></div>
    <div class="flex items-center justify-center"></div>
```

**Expected behavior**

```
    <div                                                                           | - LINE LIMIT
        class="
            m-10
            flex
            min-h-screen
            items-center
            justify-center
            rounded-2xl
            border-2
            border-red-500
            bg-indigo-500
            p-10
            shadow-2xl
        "
    ></div>
    <div class="flex items-center justify-center"></div>
```

Answer (score 4):

As today (Prettier 3.5) you just need to break the line your self wherever you needed, Prettier then will respect that.
You could see how this came to light in this issue [comment](https://github.com/prettier/prettier/issues/10918#issuecomment-854705502) , it should be easier to find this stuff ha.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: prettier 3.5 doesnt exist

Answer (score 2):

We can use Prettier 2.4. It is Disabling in Prettier 2.5

[Disabling "smart formatting" of HTML class attribute](https://github.com/prettier/prettier/issues/10918)

[2.5.0 release notes](https://prettier.io/blog/2021/11/25/2.5.0.html#collapse-html-class-attributes-onto-one-line-11827httpsgithubcomprettierprettierpull11827-by-jlongsterhttpsgithubcomjlongster)

Collapse HTML class attributes onto one line ([#11827](https://github.com/prettier/prettier/pull/11827) by [@jlongster](https://github.com/jlongster))

```html
<!-- Input -->
<div
  class="SomeComponent__heading-row d-flex flex-column flex-lg-row justify-content-start justify-content-lg-between align-items-start align-items-lg-center"
></div>

<!-- Prettier 2.4 -->
<div
  class="
    SomeComponent__heading-row
    d-flex
    flex-column flex-lg-row
    justify-content-start justify-content-lg-between
    align-items-start align-items-lg-center
  "
></div>

<!-- Prettier 2.5 -->
<div
  class="SomeComponent__heading-row d-flex flex-column flex-lg-row justify-content-start justify-content-lg-between align-items-start align-items-lg-center"
></div>
```

Comment: Why the hell that had to be disabled? o_0

Comment: To get more information, see the link in this answer.

Answer (score -1):

You should add `printWidth` to .prettierrc

```js
{
  "printWidth": 100,
  "endOfLine": "lf",
  "semi": true,
  "singleQuote": true,
}
```

Comment: Didn't work, but thank you anyway  c:

Comment: Didn't work for me too

Comment: It won't work because with latest release of prettier they decided to not move classes to a new line and always keep it on the new line due to some React developers request

Answer (score -1):

Follow following steps to avoid Break html classes in multiple lines.

1. Go to Prettier Extension Settings.
2. Set printWidth:600